# Связь между JPA, Spring data jpa и Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hibenate - одна из реализация JPA. JPA - это только спецификация.
Много где написано: **JPA - это только спецификация, она не умеет сохранять, выбирать, удалять данные из таблицы.** Для этого существуют реализации (такие как Hibernate).
Ну вот сейчас я создаю приложение с помощью Spring Boot. Для взаимодействия c БД я использую CRUD репозиторий (который является частью spring data jpa). Так вот вопросы.
1. Использование CRUD репозитория каким-то боком вообще касается Hibenate? 
2. Может ли spring data jpa использоваться без Hibenate вообще.
3. Не могу понять разницы реализации JPA и абстракции доступа к данным JPA.

Comment: Не совсем правильный подход. Для взаимодействия с бд надо писать бэкенд.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate это библиотека используемая для выполнения преобразования объектов к структурам данных реляционных БД и наоборот, что в оригинале называется ORM (Object/Relational Mapping). Обычно одному классу объектов сопоставляется одна таблица в БД, поля объекта сопоставляются к колонкам таблицы, связь между объектами в базе данных сохраняется посредством использования ключей (Primary Key/Foreign Key). Многие правила преобразования применяются автоматически библиотеками ORM, а другие необходимо описать программисту, чтобы ORM "знал" как осуществлять преобразование. В Hibernate раньше такую информацию описывали в XML, позднее появился Java Persistence API (JPA). JPA это стандартизированный программный интерфейс (API) позволяющий задать информацию необходимую для осуществления преобразования объектов к модели реляционных БД посредством аннотаций языка Java, а также там описаны интерфейсы объектов предназначенных для выполнения *Create, Read, Update, Delete* (CRUD) операций с БД. То есть, раньше каждая ORM библиотека предлагала свои собственные способы описания сопоставления объектов таблицам, а также механизмы для выполнения CRUD операций, а JPA привнес унификацию. Мне известны две реализации JPA, это Hibernate и EclipseLink.

Spring Data содержит логику позволяющую абстрагироваться от конкретных БД, например для типичных CRUD операций там есть CrudRepository позволяющий выполнять большинство типовых операций с практически любыми базами данных(реляционными и не реляционными).

А теперь конкретно ответы на твои вопросы:

1. Create, Read, Update, Delete (CRUD) это операции над данными
   хранимыми в БД. Hibernate это библиотека используемая для
   преобразования объектной модели к реляционной модели.
2. Spring Data можно использовать без Hibernate, но сам по себе Spring Data не     умеет преобразовывать объекты в структуры данных БД.
3. JPA - это API, он содержит интерфейсы EntityManager, EntityTransaction и т.д., аннотации такие как @Id, @Column, @ManyToMany и прочие. Помимо интерфейсов JPA определяет поведение реализаций описанное в документации. Реализации этого API содержат логику реализующую интерфейсы JPA и выполняющие операции над данными не противореча документации этого API.

Answer (score 1):

1. Да, Spring Data JPA под капотом использует реализацию JPA, обычно Hibernate.
2. Может использоваться с другой реализацией, типа EclipseLink или DataNucleus.
3. Спецификация автотранспортного средства: Должно иметь двигатель, кузов, четыре колеса, руль и педали, при нажатии на педаль газа ускоряться, при нажатии на педаль тормоза останавливаться, при поворотах руля поворачивать в соответствующую сторону. Реализации спецификации: ВАЗ-2101, Lamborghini Gallardo, Tesla Model 3, Caterpillar 797b. Так же спецификация JPA описывает общие принципы, которым должны соответствовать все реализации, и скрывает детали.

Comment: Спасибо. По ответу на третий вопрос. Что такое спецификация я понял. Как ее на таком же примере сравнить с абстрацией доступа к данным.

Comment: Собственно, _автотранспортное средство_ - это и есть абстракция: Не важно как именно устроен двигатель, он должен двигать, не важно как именно устроены механизмы управления, они должны управлять. А описание абстракции - это спецификация: Колёс должно быть не 3, не 6, а именно 4, руление обеспечивается именно рулём, а не рычагами и т.д.